# How to debug izpack installer?

Tags: debugging, installation, izpack

I'm creating an IzPack installer and want to know how can I debug the installer or some actions using the most automatic tools, it includes generating a debug log with the installer actions and commands executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [official documentation](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Getting+Debug+Information+from+Running+IzPack+Installers) there exists some:
`-DTRACE=true` - allows you to check current state of conditions and variables values (in GUI mode)
`-DSTACKTRACE=true` - will output complete stacktrace of the exception that caused the installer failure
`-DDEBUG=true` - debug mode, most informative but kind of hard to read sometimes